# Как на странице дать доступ ко всем элементам из базы данных mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Вообщем, я никогда не работал с базами, понятия не имею что такое php и mysql, но сделать нужно.
У меня есть много товарных страниц, на них есть цены. Эти цены мне надо брать из базы. Чтобы их подключать, я нашел способ в инете по id, но минус в том, что одна запись из двух строчек относится всего к 1й цене. А если на странице 20 разных цен и более, это вообще 40 строчек. Как написать код один раз, чтоб он выводил все id на неё, в цене я просто как-то указывал, что вот тут такой-то id и он подставляет цену.

Пример вывода двух цен (в functions.php просто подключается база, больше ничего)

```
$product = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `price_table` WHERE `id` = 1"); // композитные панели 3 мм
$product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($product);

$product2 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `price_table` WHERE `id` = 2"); // композитные панели 4 мм
$product2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($product2);

// вывод самой цены в html странице происходит так:

<?= $product['price'] ?>
<?= $product2['price'] ?>
```

Comment: 1. Как это понять, опишите пожалуйста подробней, что имеется в виду: "но минус в том, что одна запись из двух строчек относится всего к 1й цене". 2. Желательно показать структуру таблицы `price_table` и описать, как бы вы хотели выводить цены на страницы и ссылается ли как-то страница на цену.

Comment: Советую доработать описание, далее, постараюсь помочь.